# VBA scrape src instead of href

Tags: vba, excel, href, scrape

I am using the code below code but it brings the value of 'src' instead of 'href' for some reason. Anyone can help please?

```
Sub bringfox(txt As String)

Dim oHtml       As HTMLDocument
Dim oElement    As Object
Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument

maintext2 = "https://www.jjfox.co.uk/cigars/show/all.html"

With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
    .Open "GET", maintext2 & gr, False
    .send
    oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With



counter = cnt
'oElement(i).Children(0).getAttribute ("href")
Set oElement = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("products-grid products-grid--max-3-col")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
i = 0
While i < oElement.Length
    Debug.Print oElement(i).Children(0).getAttribute("href")

    i = i + 1

Wend


End Sub
```

Comment: What is txt in this context and gr ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

```
#wrapper div.category-products > ul a
```

This is a reduced version of the full selector that targets `a` tags within the products category. You then parse the `outerHTML` for the hrefs as that is where the information is located.

---

Site image (Sample view)

[image: Sample view]

---

Output from code (Sample view)

[image: Sample immediate window output]

---

Code

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim oHtml As HTMLDocument, nodeList As Object, currentItem As Long
    Const URL As String = "https://www.jjfox.co.uk/cigars/show/all.html"
    Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set nodeList = oHtml.querySelectorAll("#wrapper div.category-products > ul a")
    For currentItem = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
        On Error Resume Next
        Debug.Print Split(Split(nodeList.item(currentItem).outerHTML, "<A href=")(1), ">")(0)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next currentItem
End Sub
```

---

Or more simply, use the following

```
For currentItem = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print nodeList.item(currentItem).href
    On Error GoTo 0
Next currentItem
```